# How to run sql n times increasing variable and after joining results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've a transact table (historical) with a `CreatedDate`, this transact is related to employee transact table. (inner join in transact_id)

This being said, comes the problem: I need to query these table and get the state by month , because during the year, the `CreatedDate` can change. e.g. An employee update in July will create a new line, but this shouldn't affect the March total.

The solution looks like a **forech**, but how can I join all lines at the end? The result should be something like:

- January - $123
- February - $234
- March - $123
- ...

I get the last state of each employee with this:

```
select AllTransact.id_employee, AllTransact.id_department from (

select id_employee, id_department, rank() over (partition by id_employee order by created_date desc) desc_rank
from Transact_Employee TransEmployee
inner join Transact     on TransEmployee.ID_Transact = Transact.ID_Transact 
                        and Transact.Status = 8 
                        and Transact.Created_Date < @currentMonth) AllTransact

where desc_rank = 1
```

*I don't want to copy and past all the code 12 times. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can partition over many columns. `rank() OVER (partition BY [id_employee],datepart(month,[Created_Date]) ORDER BY [Created_Date] DESC)` will give you what you have now but for each month (and it doesn't care what year that month is in so you either need to partition by year too or add limit on created_date).